# How to force a chrome extension autoupdate from the extension itself?

Tags: plugins, google-chrome-extension

When we push a new version to our server, the old extensions deployed take some time (<7hours in the docs, but I have seen more) to update themselves. The problem is that these OLD extensions may talk to the NEW services/api deployed on the server, thus raising conflicts. And those are very hard to hunt down...

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Use versioning on the server-side. I don't think there's any way to force an auto-update.

Comment: This seems like a very big architectural challenge. But yes that would be a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force autoupdate but you can pass api version along with the server response and have extension notify users to upgrade if it is outdated (response version doesn't match hardcoded into extension version).

**UPDATE**

Ok I just reread the question and looks like author is talking about the extension gallery. In this case you can't just point a user to the gallery as it doesn't allow you to reinstall an extension without uninstalling first anymore (it used to a while ago). In this case, to force reinstall you would have to  either ask users to hit "Refresh now" button on the their `chrome://extensions/` page, or download and install your extension's crx directly, which has the following (scary) format:

```
http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D<EXTENSION_ID_HERE>%26uc%26lang%3Den-US&prod=chrome
```

Comment: Ok thanks. so basically that would mean make him download the latest CRX? That would crush the old version he installed?

Comment: @Maz I would display desktop notification saying new version is available with a link to crx. Launching crx would update the extension if it is already installed.

Comment: Are you sure? Deep-linking to a .crx isn't the normal way to install an extension.

Comment: @bzlm What do you mean by deep linking? Downloading and launching crx is the normal way of installing an extension not hosted in gallery. Even if it is, you can still point to crx (just need to build crx url which is a bit tricky) or just to gallery profile.

Comment: @serg sorry to bring up an old post but I tried that link (adding my extension's id in place of <EXTENSION_ID_HERE>) and it gives me: `error-unknownApplication`. Is that link only for apps installed from the chrome web store?