# Is there a way for a packaged hosted chrome extension to request chrome updates it?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-extension

Usually, the browser checks for extension updates every few hours and you can manually override this by clicking the "update extensions now" button. I want to make this seamless and give my extension the ability to update the moment one is available. Via Ajax, it checks worth the server and knows an update is available. I want it to them tell the browser to update it. Is this possible?

This is a packaged extension that is hosted externally: http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/hosting.html

**UPDATE: This is the working code!**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World 2 again 17!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js (the content script that listens for document click and tells background to update)

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.body.onclick = function()
    {
        chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck(function(status) {
                if (status == "update_available") {
                    console.log("update pending...");
                } else if (status == "no_update") {
                    console.log("no update found");
                } else if (status == "throttled") {
                    console.log("Oops, I'm asking too frequently - I need to back off.");
                }
        });
    }
}
```

main.js (the background script)

```
//You need to put reload in this callback
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(details) {
  console.log("updating to version " + details.version);
  chrome.runtime.reload();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a chrome extension autoupdate from the extension itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742059/how-to-force-a-chrome-extension-autoupdate-from-the-extension-itself)

Comment: @KingCronus It's not a duplicate. Mine is a self-hosted packaged app. It's not served by the Chrome Web Store, so that question/answer are not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-requestUpdateCheck)? Your code could be something like this:

```
chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck(function(status,details){});
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable(function(details){
    console.log('Updating to version: ' + details.version);
    chrome.runtime.reload();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I think it *might* work. I did this and it worked once, but all the other times I tried it, it prints to the console that it's updating, but then it never updates. No matter how many times I try, it won't until I do the manual way by clicking "update extensions now". See me code above.

Comment: It **sees** the update! The console prints out that it's updating and it shows the correct version there, and the extensions page shows it disappear for a second and then reappear but as the old version! No matter how many times I try, it just keeps doing that. But that means Chrome **IS** loading the update, just not installing it. (Also, I added a setTimeout delay but it still doesn't fix this)

Comment: I believe I have it working! Your second suggestion was the key. I put the reload in the `chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable` listener and now it's working!

Comment: @DonRhummy Thanks for letting me know, I was hoping it would work out.